# Playing a sound notification using Google Web Toolkit

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, audio

Is it possible to play a sound notification using Google Web Toolkit which will be translated to Javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since GWT 2.2 you can play audio with: `com.google.gwt.media.client.Audio` class.

API:
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/media/client/Audio.html

Sample:

```
private Audio mistakeAudio;

{
    mistakeAudio = Audio.createIfSupported();
    mistakeAudio.setSrc("style/failure.wav");
}

public void mistakeSound(){
    mistakeAudio.play();
}
```

Comment: where is the `style` folder? Is it in the same directory as the .java file, or is it in the web directory?

Comment: @MarioStoilov its the URL, check http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/media/client/MediaBase.html#setSrc(java.lang.String)

Comment: If you use maven put the file here: `src/main/webapp/style/failure.wav`. Otherwise just in `war/style/failure.wav`. Basically the same location you put any other static files, like css, and your main html page. Works a charm for me.

Comment: You can use
`public interface Media extends ClientBundle {
 /** beep sound */
 @DoNotEmbed
 @Source("beep.wav")
 DataResource beep();
}` and then `audio.setSrc(MEDIA.beep().getSafeUri().asString())`

Comment: Audio avoz = Audio.createIfSupported();
                avoz.setSrc("./avoz/ob.mp3");
                avoz.play();

Answer (score 4):

Try using this library: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-voices/

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible, [scriptaculous (a js library) has a sound.js](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/sound) which is an example of how to do it. The [source](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/blob/4b49fd8884920d4ee760b0194431f4f433f878df/src/sound.js) is under 50 lines of code.